# Can't create or edit files when VM is not connected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, connection, virtual-machine

Everything works when I connect the VM from my PC but it seems like VM is being restricted when I disconnect from it, any idea why its happening. I need to say that its not being shutdown when I disconnect.

I am using Windows servers EC2 type and everything is usual. I am using it for my backend server and I don't want to keep my actual PC all the time. I can send, create and edit their name from my frontend when I have a connection to it as I said before.

I am using a python script and running it in order to process the file and create a output.

Thanks for any help!

What I have tried:

1. I have enabled permission for the folder.
2. Enabled "Offline Files" feature.
3. Restarting the VM.